# Adding Keyboard Shortcut to open the Chrome Extension that I created

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have made a chrome extension that saves inputs and tab-links (basically a sticky note for chrome).
I want to add a keyboard shortcut to open that extension in my chrome, but here chrome://extensions/shortcuts I can't see my uploaded extension.

do I need to add permission in my menifest.json?
or anything else?

by the way here's my manifest.json.

```
{
    "name": "Sticky",
  "description": "saves input",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "version": "1.1",
    "action":{
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_icon": "nani.jpg"
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

Comment: Add `document.addEventListener('keyup', ...);` to your injected script

Comment: Can you show your js files?

Answer (score 0):

here,

```
let links=[]
let input = document.getElementById("in")
let ulli = document.getElementById("ul")
let save = document.getElementById("save")
let tab = document.getElementById("tab");

let linksfronlocalstorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("links"))

if(linksfronlocalstorage){
    links = linksfronlocalstorage
    printlist(links)
}


save.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    links.push(input.value)
    input.value = ""
    localStorage.setItem("links", JSON.stringify(links))
    printlist(links)
})

tab.addEventListener("click", function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    links.push(tabs[0].url)
    localStorage.setItem("links", JSON.stringify(links))
    printlist(links)
    })
})

function printlist(anything){
    let listitems = ""  //string
    for(let i=0;i<anything.length; i++){
       listitems += "<li><a target = '_blank' href='" + anything[i] + "'>" + anything[i] + "</a></li>"
       //or template string
    }
    ulli.innerHTML = listitems
}
 //del when double clicked

 let doubleclickdel = document.getElementById("del")

 doubleclickdel.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
    localStorage.clear()
    links = []
    printlist(links)
 })
 
//ENTER KEY FOR SAVING INPUT
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        save.click();
    }
});
```